# How to write a replace function in c

Tags: c, replace

Write a function that will return a value in which `i`-th byte of `x` has been replaced by `b`:

```
unsigned replace_f (unsigned x, int i, unsigned char b){

}
```

EX: `replace_f(0x12345678, 2, 0xBC) --> 0x12BC5678`

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? Maybe we can point out the errors in it.

Comment: Well I'm new to C, so I don't know exactly where to begin.

Comment: @sebi: while we're always happy to help you solve specific problems, most of us don't have the time to teach you a language - which is essentially what you seem to be asking. Please take some time to learn about C first, then feel free to come back with a specific problem we can help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned replace_f (unsigned x, int i, unsigned char b){
    unsigned char *place = (unsigned char*)&x;
    place[sizeof(int)-i] = b;
    return x;
}
```

Assume little endian

Comment: You should note that you assume little endian

Answer (score 2):

Didn't try out, but this could work:

```
unsigned replace_f (unsigned x, int i, unsigned char b){
    char *c;

    c = (char *)&x;
    c[i] = b;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You should note that you assume big endian

Comment: Ÿeah.. I should, but also I assume x86 :D

Comment: No, you don't. x86 is little endian, which is not what your code supports

Comment: Well yeah, so why would you want me to note big endian?

Comment: Because that's what your code does, the OP is counting bytes from the MSB, not from the LSB.